# Strange .htaccess behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For a project I'm working on we are doing a TLD change and I'm setting up both standard Redirects and RedirectMatch rules, when trying to test some redirects I have a strange problem, I have example below:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 307 /foldername/   https://www.newdomain.com/foldername/
Redirect 307 /testredirectfile.html https://www.newdomain.com/testredirectfile.html
```

Im using 307's so i can test these pages without them becoming cached / permenent

But when i test this by visiting https://www.oldsite.com/foldername/, it redirects to https://www.newdomain.com/foldername/?perma=foldername!, there is nothing on the target domain in the .htaccess which would cause this behaivour

Has anyone experienced this?

I try to understand what is happening before it's attempted on a larger scale.

Comment: can you post the .htaccess on the target domain? and what is the page showing?

Answer (score 0):

what had happened is i had other rules underneath the redirect so it was i guess running through the entire htaccess and applying all of the rules, i had taken out [L] as this didnt work with the

Redirect 307 /foldername/   https://www.newdomain.com/foldername/

Adjusted my code to use 'RewriteRule' with the [R=307,L] and seems have a solved it, sorry for the dumb question i was pulling my hair out at the time